# How to handle SoapClient Fault In PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client, soapfault

I am calling a third party web service to get the user detail by the supplied credential. Below is my Soap Client Request.

```
$client = new \SoapClient($url, array("exception" => 0));        
$auth = '
<wsse:Security SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username>' . $userName . '</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password>' . $password . '</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>';
$authvalues = new \SoapVar($auth, XSD_ANYXML);
$header1 = new \SoapHeader("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", $authvalues, true);   
$header2 = new \SoapHeader("http://xmlns.myweb.com/FulfillProductRequest/V1", "v1");    
$header3 = new \SoapHeader("http://xmlns.myweb.com/ParameterType/V2", "v2");    
$header4 = new \SoapHeader("http://xmlns.myweb.com/RequestHeader/V3", "v3");

$header = array();    
$header[] = $header1;    
$header[] = $header2;    
$header[] = $header3;    
$header[] = $header4;                
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);    
$res = $client->FulfillProduct($FulfillProductRequest);
```

When i am calling the WSDL,if i am getting the success response then there is no issue.

But if there is any error come in soapFault then my code shows fatal error.

Anybody have any idea how to handle the SoapFault plz share.

Thanks in anvance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your `$res = $client→FulfillProduct($FulfillProductRequest);` in a `try { } catch() {}`.

For example:

```
try { 
  $res = $client→FulfillProduct($FulfillProductRequest);
} catch(Exception $e) {
  // An error has occured.
  // All information about the error has been stored in variable $e
  print_r($e);
}
```

Be aware, that you can set the `SoapClient` to never throw exceptions with your settings, so look into that first.

Comment: I am using the try catch block. But unable to handle the fatal error. Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Server] XXXXXXXXXXXXX XXX XXXXX

Comment: In your parameters for the SoapClient, you have set `exceptions => 0`. Remove that, as it is preventing the SoapClient from throwing exceptions.

Comment: After removing also it is not working. I am getting the same error.(fatal error)

Comment: Can you add the actual Fatal Error to your example?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Server] Product does not exists in 
D:\cvs_local2\app\MWAPI\FulfillProduct.php:79 Stack trace: #0 
D:\cvs_local2\app\MWAPI\FulfillProduct.php(79): SoapClient->__call('FulfillProduct', Array) #1 
D:\cvs_local2\app\MWAPI\FulfillProduct.php(79): SoapClient->FulfillProduct(Object(Application\MWAPI\FulfillProductRequest)) #2

Comment: Have you omitted line 79 from your example? It appears that your error is not even directly relating to your SOAP actions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103284/discussion-between-manoj-and-bjorn-schijff).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone.

```php
$options =  ['trace'    => true,
            'debug'    => false,
            "exceptions" => true, 
            'version'  => SOAP_1_2,
            'connection_timeout' => 15];

$wsdl = "http://test.com?wsdl";

try {

    $soapClient=new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);

} catch (SoapFault $e) {

    logError($e->getMessage(),$e->getCode());
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).